# Computer Science self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Comment: A random selection with not a single question from May (a third of beta runtime, and a fourth of all questions!), and most from the first half of April? Unlikely. ;) Should we not evaluate what we do *now*, rather than what we did six weeks ago (at the beginning of public beta, that is)? Anyway, I will have a look tomorrow.

Comment: @Raphael We pull questions from about 30-40 days ago to make sure they had time to be answered, edited, etc. etc. Not to worry, there will be other evaluations in the future so it'll balance out. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 8):

[Why does the splay tree rotation algorithm take into account both the parent and grandparent node?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/splay-tree-rotation-algorithm)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question, the type many students are likely to have trouble with. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 6):

[Attack on hash functions that do not satisfy the one-way property](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/attack-on-hash-functions-that-do-not-satisfy-the-one-way-property)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Well-composed question and equally good answer.

Comment: The question is a nice HW question. The answer gives hints for the main ideas, but not a full answer. An additional complete-detailed answer could have made this thread much more interesting.

Comment: Nowadays we would very much welcome this question on the [crypto.se] site of course.

Answer (score 5):

[How does variance in task completion time affect makespan?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/how-does-variance-in-task-completion-time-affect-makespan)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question. One good answer.

Answer (score 3):

[HALF CLIQUE - NP Complete Problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/half-clique-np-complete-problem)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The question is nice: the OP elaborates just enough to show that the problem is not with the specific question, but with understanding in the large. The answers address that nicely. Also, they complement each other: Alex' is quite elaborate while Louis' contains just the bare facts.

Comment: my issue with that question, is that the OP seeks for only a hint. This makes sense to him, but is less useful for others with the same question in mind. One thing that is missing is a link to (the plenty) lecture notes formally solving the question.

Answer (score 2):

[What is required for universal analogue computation?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/what-is-required-for-universal-analogue-computation)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Question a little bit too open and under-defined. Nevertheless, it attracted some good answers.

Comment: The answer barely crosses the NARQ-threshold. As a consequence, the answers are less to the point as they might have been.

Comment: A classical question of a non-expert: The OP has a clear idea of what he wants, but has no means to define it (thus cannot google it, since it is not clear what should be googled). On one hand, this makes the question look "open handed". On the other hand, the comments/answers clarify the need for a definition, and give very good directions for the OP to continue exploring his idea. "Out of the eater came forth meat, and out of the strong came forth sweetness" (figuratively, Judges14:14)

Answer (score 1):

[Where to get graphs to test my search algorithms against?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/where-to-get-graphs-to-test-my-search-algorithms-against)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The question lacks detail (I guess the OP was not aware of its depth) but is interesting in itself. Sadly, the OP never returned; I think with some revision, this question could have become outstanding. Nick's answer is reasonable but it is unclear whether it applies to the OP's original problem.

Answer (score 0):

[What is a good reference to learn about state transition systems?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/what-is-a-good-reference-to-learn-about-state-transition-systems)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The problem with this question is that the OP seemed to want one thing, but asked for another. The answer provided only feedback for what was directly asked.

Comment: Classic reference request, but for so broad an area that it borders on "general reference" (which we don't have).

Answer (score -2):

[Is there evidence that using dynamic languages has an impact on productivity?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/is-there-evidence-that-using-dynamic-languages-has-an-impact-on-productivity)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The kind of question that really needs an answer from the research community. Question itself was a little too broad. No comprehensive answer given.

Comment: I stand by my comment from then: barely ontopic, if at all. Probably not answerable.

Comment: A question is legitimate but poorly phrased and the community could not get much feedback from the OP. Yet several references were provided that might be useful.

Comment: I don't see that it is off-topic. Questions such as the one in the title are the subject of empirical software engineering, which is CS, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score -3):

[Extending the implementation of a Queue using a circular array](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/extending-the-implementation-of-a-queue-using-a-circular-array)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Could have easily been a StackOverflow question.

Comment: It is not clear from the question what answers should focus on. Apparently, the OP never came back to clarify.

Comment: as Raphael said - the question is yet unclear (to me). It's hard to judge the relevancy of the answers.

Comment: This could have been an SO question, but it would have called for different answers. I think it's had a reasonable CS answer. This may not be what the asker was after, but it's what future visitors will get.

Answer (score -4):

[Ordering elements so that some elements don't come between others](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/ordering-elements-so-that-some-elements-dont-come-between-others)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: An artificial question. No adequate answers provided.

Comment: Interesting question and well-posed. Still open, therefore downvote; it is probably a hard question that requires a considerable amount of (creative) thought, though, so I am not too concerned.